# Output of code not as expected in Javascript, reason why when using +=2?

Tags: javascript

Explain why when this code runs, the code would start at the second index instead of the third index. I believed the output would be clx, when the output is hello.

```
var str = "ahceclwlxo";

for(var i=1; i<str.length; i+=2){
    console.log(str[i]);
}
```

Comment: Because arrays are indexed from 0 and you start at 1? Also, +=2 doesn't magically make the index jump 3 places, which would be necessary to get `clx`

Comment: The loop executes for the initial value (`i = 1`) and, **after** that execution, it runs the increment routine (`i += 2`). As arrays start with index `0`, you first access the second element (`i == 1`) and then you go to the fourth element (`i == 3`), etc. If you want to start with the third element (where `i == 2`) and read every character after that, just set the initial value as `2` and increment by `1`: `for ( var i = 2; i < str.length; i++ )`

Comment: As a sidenote, if you need to do incrementing **before** the loop condition is evaluated, you could use a `do-while` loop: `do { i += 2; /* more instructions */ } while ( i < str.length );`

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in js starts at position 0. So the code starts at position 1 (h) then jump to 1 + 2 = 3 (e) and so on

If you want to show clx you have to do this:

```js
var str = "ahceclwlxo";

for(var i=2; i<str.length; i+=3){
    console.log(str[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the string as an array... Which is fine in JavaScript... What you need however is to start the array at the proper first index `0`... Also notice that I use the length minus one due to the index starting at zero.

Here is your code fixed and will output... every other character... not the expected ones.

```
var str = "ahceclwlxo";

for(var i=0; i<str.length - 1; i+=2){
    console.log(str[i]);
}
```

On mobile I did not check the output... it's not what you expect since you're looking for `clx`. The above will output `accwx` as seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/36nkzvs8/ I made the wrong assumption that your numbers were correct other than starting the array at 0.

Proper answer is above... Hopefully the fiddle I wrote will be helpful to you or another with a similar issue to play with the output.